# Woocommerce checkout + cart white opacity class="processing"

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I come to you withh an issue that I've been going crazy about, 
I'm building a woocommerce for a client, but when I'm on the cart and I click on check out, the form goes "white", then goes to check out, and on check out, when the page load, a form is "white", and when I click on "proceed to paypal", both forms go "white". By inspecting, I noticed the thing changing was the add of a class "processing" to the form, but I can't find any effect to that class, and I can't manage to overide it, does someone know how I can fix this?

[image]
[image]

[url of project](http://clients.studio24-24.com/aoc/order/)

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to override it? I'm pretty sure that's the jQuery blockUI plugin and it's designed to keep you from making changes while the form is being processed, mostly to prevent errors and double processing.

Comment: Because it's unesthetic...

Comment: So I have found the solution for the cart page, it was in the cart.js file, the class processing triggered an offerlay, so i reduced the opacity of it, but for the check out page, i modified the checkout.js and it doesn't change it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the solution : it was in the cart.js and checkout.js file (woocommerce > assets > js), the class processing triggered an offerlay, so i reduced the opacity of it.

```
if ( ! is_blocked( $node ) ) {
        $node.addClass( 'processing' ).block( {
            message: null,
            overlayCSS: {
                background: '#fff',
                opacity: 0.6
            }
        } );
    }
```

and

```
if ( 1 !== form_data['blockUI.isBlocked'] ) {
    $form.block({
        message: null,
        overlayCSS: {
        background: '#fff',
        opacity: 0.6
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Css

```
 .woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay {

  position: relative! important;

  display: none ! important;

  }
```